# Blade cutting off half of string

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm sending user details to a view with:

```
    $transformed = new User;
    $transformed->firstname = $user->firstname;
    $transformed->lastname = $user->lastname;
    $transformed->email = $user->email;

    return View::make('account.settings', ['user' => $transformed]);
```

if I do `dd($transformed)` before `View::make` then I see a complete email address, but the template cuts off everything from the "@" and before:

```
Should be: parent@parent.com
Is: parent.com
```

In the blade template, I have:

```
{{ $user->email }}
```

Why is it cutting off the start?

Here's the full view file:

```
@extends('account')

@section('content')

    <section class="site-section site-content account-section">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="account-header">Account Settings</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">

                    <form role="form" method="POST" action="/auth/register" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <h3>Basic Details</h3>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <label for="register-email">Email address</label>
                                <input id="register-email" type="text" name="email" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{ $user->email }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <label for="register-firstname">First Name</label>
                                <input id="register-firstname" type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{ $user->firstname }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <label for="register-lastname">Last Name</label>
                                <input id="register-lastname" type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{ $user->lastname }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-actions">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-effect-ripple btn-lg btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Update Details</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <h3>
                        </h3>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END row -->


        </div>
    </section>

@stop
```

Comment: I just created a simple view with object as variable and assigned an email to it, then printed the result in view and everything is ok. The answer below is not correct for me as Laravel does not process the content between {{}} as Blade itself. Try ```{{dd($user)}}``` in the view itself and check what is the output.

Comment: Doing that, I get `object(User)` with `["email"]=> string(17) "parent@parent.com"`

Comment: Can you please post your full view file. Can you also check the *source* of the generated HTML page - is the email missing, or is part of it just hidden?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange thanks, I've just edited with the full view file.

Comment: Actually the problem only exists with Blade keywords like @parent and only if you are using the layouts from what I see. The trick with ```explode('@', $email)``` and then concat it with @ sign would work I think.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange the value in the source is missing.

Comment: @babbaggeii - what if you try `{{{ $user->email }}}` - notice the 3x `{{{ `instead of 2x `{{`

Comment: @babbaggeii - also - long shot - technically this shouldnt matter - but can you change the example in the object to `example@example.com` and see if you get the same problem?

Comment: @babbaggeii - also - one other thing - if none of the above works - can you please *also* change the email to `another@parent.com` - do you see `another.com` or `parent.com`? I'm guessing `another.com`?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange It works fine if it's a different email address, so it looks like a bug with the `@parent` directive. Triple braces doesn't solve it.

Comment: I already mentioned it in my previous comment. Every single email will work if you are not using Blade keywords like ```@parent```, ```@extend``` etc. Also the example with parent@parent.com will work fine if you are in master template(layout or just template that does not extend any layout) as there is no parent file that you can refer to. So it is definitely some kind of bug, nothing else.

Comment: I can confirm this bug is also currently in Laravel 5. I'll open a Github issue on it now

Comment: Ok - I've lodged an issue on Github - seems to affect both L4 and L5. Watch here to see if it gets fixed or what the reply is: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7888

Comment: @babbaggeii did my answer help? If so, would you mind marking it as as the answer please? :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the comments that this is a bug in Laravel itself as `@parent`, `@extends` etc are reserved words in the blade template engine.

A simple work around it to simply replace the `@` symbol with it's HTML Entity equivalent (`&#64;`). So, please try the following snippet:

```
{{ str_replace('@', '&#64;', $user->email) }}
```

This can also be used in `mailto` protocol links, as so:

```
<a href="mailto:{{ str_replace('@', '&#64;', $email) }}">
    {{str_replace('@', '&#64;', $email)}}
</a>
```

For reference, here is a list of all HTML Entities (the list is far too long to add to this answer): http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm